# Representing D- and L- in chemical names

Tags: formatting, chemstyle

Using LaTeX, how does one typeset the D- and L- prefixes, which refer to dextrorotatory and levorotatory isomers. I have tried `\footnotesize~D\normalsize` and it looks okay, but didn't know if there was a better or more correct approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do for example `\textsc{d}-Glucose`, which requests small caps. This only looks good if the font family you're using actually provides small caps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure that is correct. I tried `\textsc{D}` and it didn't work -- now I see why.

Answer (score 5):

It would probably overkill to load the package just for this purpose but the [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package provides a lot of IUPAC naming commands. Amongst these are `\D` and `\L` for the FISCHER stereo descriptors. With default settings they are only valid inside the `\iupac{}` command in order not to overwrite the usual definition of `\L`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\iupac{\D-Glucose}
\iupac{\L-Alanine}

\end{document}
```

[image]