# Chemical compound names in the "Reference"

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using EasyThesis template to write my thesis. I use bibtex to look after my entries in "References" section. There is one entry in the reference like :

```
@Article{sakya1994lyotropic,
  Title                    = {Lyotropic phase behaviour of n-octyl-1-O-$\beta$-{\footnotesize{D}}-glucopyranoside and its thio derivative n-octyl-1-S-$\beta$-{\footnotesize{D}}-glucopyranoside},
  Author                   = {Sakya, P. and Seddon, J. M. and Templer, R. H.},
  Journal                  = {Journal de Physique {II}},
  Year                     = {1994},
  Pages                    = {1311--1331},
  Volume                   = {4}
}
```

I expect the 'D' in the title should appear capital once finish compile, but I get 'd'.

I tried many ways to get the 'D' by removing the curly brackets `{}` but avail. Additionally, I need to use `\footnotesize{D}` because the D is smaller size.

Hope I get some help.

Comment: Package `chemmacros` is great here. It should do what you want, also in your main text. [Representing D- and L- in chemical names](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41090)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164527/using-iupac-d-or-d-in-a-paragraph-environment/164548#164548